# ajax on success to table

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I'll try to explain the best I can

this is a .net application

I have a javascript function that calls a webmethod, and that method should return some results

I get response as multiple objects, with param_name and param_value (number of objects and different param_names depends on the request)

now I am having trouble with displaying that data on the page, currently I am trying to return results as a list of dictionaries but don't really now how to go through that and show it on page (I am used to work with datatables and grid, but didn't find a way to work with that and javascript/ajax yet)

i would like results to be shown in something like this

```
      param_name1   param_name2    param_name3
      parav_value1   param_value2   parav_value3
      parav_value1   param_value2   parav_value3
      parav_value1   param_value2   parav_value3
```

ajax

```
   $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'Reports.aspx/getReport',
            data: "{'jsonObject':'" + rp + "'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (results) {
                alert('success');


            },
            error: function (err) {
                alert(err.status + " - " + err.statusText);
            }
        });
```

after this alert i should go through the results and show them

any suggestion is welcome, if there is some easier way I will be glad to listen to it

Comment: How are your data formatted in your results var ?

Comment: currently as a list of dictinaries (one dictionary-> one response object I get), but I can easily change that

Comment: If it's only a display problem, I guess you should think about using html <table>. Could you show us an export of 'results' (console.log for example)

Comment: now i have this in results.d - http://i61.tinypic.com/2iglqfc.png

also, I have ready code to return data to javascript in DataTable, but I don't know how to get and show that data, I always get Error 500, internal server error when I return datatable type from webmethod